# drupal 'node' table regenerate

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 installation in a shared hosting server and I am in a situation that the server provider removed some entries from `node` table when the database size crossed 1gb limit.

I lost a lot of entries, but some data exists in other tables with `entity_id` reference numbers.

I can query my data using the references from other tables but drupal interface could not show the data because of these missing entries.

So, how could I safely regenerate the entries into `node` table and its tables references ?

Where can I get the information about the usage of fields in drupal tables?
If possible, a step by step guide would be very helpful.

Comment: If you have a full complete data base , you can use backup and migrate module to export/import data safely https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Comment: @Fky, thank you for the comment. My requirement is to regenerate the data in back end mysql database for missing entries.

Comment: check if there is any node_revision table in your database. Assuming you have no database backup you can not recover your deleted node. In future you can use different module to keep database backup, monitor events in admin panel, keep node revision etc. Have a look on this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/645/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-deleted-node

Comment: @Vijayakumar read backup and migrate module documentation, you can restore data with it

Answer (score 0):

Jahangir is on the right track. The revision info will get you 90% of the way there.

My example makes the assumption that only the node table has been affected by these spurious deletions.

Start by getting any revisions that don't have a related node

```
$result = db_query('SELECT nid, MAX(vid) AS vid, uid, title, `timestamp`, `status`, `comment`, promote, sticky FROM {node_revision}
WHERE nid NOT IN (SELECT nid FROM {node}) GROUP BY nid');
```

You could do this next part using a node object, but given that we just need the node entries I would do it directly to the db:

```
foreach ($result as $record) {
  //You might be able to get the created date by looking at the earliest revision
  $min_result = db_query('SELECT nid, MIN(vid) as vid, `timestamp` FROM {node_revision} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid' => $record->nid));
  $created = $min_result->fetchColumn(4);

  $new_node = db_insert('node')
    ->fields(array(
      'nid' => $record->nid,
      'vid' => $record->vid,
      'type' => 'YOU CANNOT GET THIS',
      'language' => $record->language,
      'title' => $record->title,
      'uid' => $record->uid,
      'created' => $created,
      'updated' => $record->timestamp,
      //you get the idea...
    ));

}
```

I wasn't able to find a way to retrieve the content type using the revisions, so that is the weakness of the solution. Assuming all of your field data is still in place, this should get your nodes back.

*disclaimer: I wasn't able to fake up an environment that resembled the problem presented here so this code is based on my experience and a little Googling. This hasn't been tested, but I hope it is still valuable. Downvotes humbly accepted.

Comment: 'type' => 'YOU CANNOT GET THIS'; Is linking the uid is enough for this?

Comment: Can I safely copy the content of vuuid field in node_revision table to node table?

Comment: The uid isn't related to the node type. The node type is only stored in the node table. If your content types have some distinguishing field or set of fields, you could query the field_data_fieldname tables to see if the nid is there. You do not want to use vuuid as your uuid on the node table. You would want to use the uuid module's uuid_generate method. You call uuid_generate() and get a callback for the appropriate generation function  then call user_call_func('callbac_from_uuid') to get a uuid. Add the uuid to the array used for db_insert.